# What are the differences between security policy and security mechanism with operating systems

Tags: security, operating-system, policies

What is the difference between the two as I am not sure.

This is in reference with operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is overly vague - please cite a specific reference; please give some context.

In general, however:

> "Mechanism *enables* policy".

"Policy" is *what* you want to do; "mechanism" is the *how* that lets you do it.

IMHO...

PS:
Here is (one of?) the original paper(s) that refers to "separation of policy and mechanism":

[HYDRA - The kernel of a multiprocessor operating system, William Allan. Wulf](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2752&context=compsci)

Here's another (slightly more amusing) discussion, from the "politically incorrect" Mick O'Pedia:

http://mickopedia.org/mickify.py?topic=Policies_and_mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

Security policy is just a statement about what is allowed and not allowed to do in a system while security mechanism is a procedure how to implement the security policy.It is said to be a tool,methodology or procedures for security enforcement.

Answer (score 0):

The same as the difference between the words "policy" and "mechanism": WHAT you're trying to accomplish and HOW you're going to accomplish it.

Comment: Just trying to grasp the actual difference between the two in terms of operating systems, not the words itself.